# Segoe UI for math mode

Tags: math-mode, fonts, miktex

How to set a font for math mode? I would like to have something like Segoe UI of something similar. Thank you

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{firamath-otf}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
x+y=45
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Where does this font comes from? Which type of font is it? Which tex engine do you use? Can you change the engine, if needed?

Comment: Segoe has no math symbols. You can try `\usepackage{firamath-otf}`

Comment: I use XeLaTex and I give an error that I added to my question

Comment: @MarciaCross: It looks like that you have not an updated system. Try to update `unicode-math` and `fontspec` and `latex3`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want Segoe UI specifically, you can select all the symbols it contains with the `range=` option of `\setmathfont`, with another font such as Fira Math as your fallback for the rest.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale = MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{Segoe UI}[
   Scale = 1.0,
   BoldFont = Segoe UI Semibold ,
   BoldItalicFont = Segoe UI Semibold Italic ]

\setmathfont{Fira Math}
\setmathfont{Segoe UI}[
  range= { up/{Latin,latin,Greek,greek,Digits},
           "2B-"2F,"3A-"3E,`¬,`·,`°,`±,`×,`÷,
           `←,`↑,`→,`↓,`↔,`↗,`↙,
           `Ω,`∂,`∆,`∏,`∑,`−,`∕,`∙,`∞,`∟,`∩,`∴,
           `∶,`≈,`≠,`≡,`≤,`≥,`⋲,
           `■,`□,`▪,`▫,`◊,`○,
           "02B0-"036F
         }]
\setmathfont{Segoe UI Semibold}[range=bfup/{Latin,latin,Greek,greek,Digits}]
\setmathfont{Segoe UI Italic}[range=it/{Latin,latin,Greek,greek}]
\setmathfont{Segoe UI Semibold Italic}[range=bfit/{Latin,latin,Greek,greek}]

\begin{document}

Segoe UI \textit{italic} \textbf{bold \textit{italic}} 0

\( \lim_{n \to 0} \frac{\partial}{\partial t}
    \int_n^\infty  \pm \symup{i} \sqrt{\symup{\pi} t} \symbfit{b} \times
                                 \symbfup{j} \,\mathup{d}t
    \approx \increment \symbfit{B} \)

\end{document}
```

[image: Segoe UI font sample]

You can tweak this further if you like.  For example, you’d want to add `"02B0-"036F`, or at least `\hat`, to the range of all the math alphabets if you wanted to use the combining accent.

Comment: Can I use Segoe UI Semibold for subindexes? I do this in MathType to avoid too thin strokes in subindexes?

Comment: @RodolfoOviedo Either make your sub-indices bold (which this code maps to the semi-bold font) or set it with `sscript-features=`.

Comment: @RodolfoOviedo There’s also an option to `\setmathfont` that selects a font for super/sub-scripts. See the `unicode-math` manual.

Comment: Many thank! Segoe UI Symbol is another option for some glyphs.