# \usepackage{firamath-otf} error

Tags: packages

What means these error mease by using

```
\usepackage{firamath-otf}
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{firamath-otf}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
x+y=45
\end{equation}
```

The compilation was by XeLaTex

[image]

Comment: The error messages indicate that either your `unicode-math-xetex` or `expl3` package is outdated. Try updating your packages from the MiKTeX console.

Comment: Please do not ask questions twice! This is a duplicate of your first question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/506501/segoe-ui-for-math-mode. Wait for an answer or add more information to make your **first** question clearer, for example add the first line of your log file to show us the used tex distribution and version number.

Comment: @siracusa, I don't have these package in MiKTeX console. I have `unicode-math` installed yesterday and `exp-testopt`

Comment: I guess `unicode-math-xetex` is part of `unicode-math`; `expl3` seems to be part of `l3kernel`. Is the latter also up-to-date?

Comment: That package has to be installed, it's required by `unicode-math`

Comment: Is it possible to open MiKTex Console in cmd? I can't find it suddenly

Answer (score 2):

Open MiKTeX Console, click on `Packages` (marked red 1), add `firamath` in search field (marked red 2), click on symbol marked red 3, select needed package (marked red 4) and click on + sign (marked red 5) to install.

[image: firamath-package]

Simular you can checkif it is installed or install `unicode-math` with:

[image: unicode-math]

But at last best would be to have a complete MiKTeX installed, then you need not to install missing packages ...

Please see column marked with red arrow and 1: There you can see the date when the package was installed or an missing date shows you it is not installed yet ...