# Why is \triangleright printed as a question mark in a box?

Tags: fonts, symbols

I took a piece of code from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87407/iterating-through-comma-separated-arguments) to indicate the steps taken in my software. However, while using `$\triangleright$` it shows like this:

[image]

It didn't do that before so somewhere along the way I made some changes with unintended consequences. I wrote a bunch of packages and a document class to get here which I can't really share with you, so I hope it suffices to mention that I use `XeLaTeX` and the segoe ui font from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/506501/segoe-ui-for-math-mode). I read here and there that it requires the `latexsym` package, but I didn't need that before.

EDIT: as I was writing the question I realized I could try to comment out the font selection, and I did, and it worked. So my question still stands and indeed it should suffice to mention that I use the segoe ui font as posted in that link.

ANOTHER EDIT: Using `$\rhd$` instead works, but is kinda ugly. Are there other triangle-pointing-right symbols that I could use?

Comment: Exactly which code? Please provide a full but minimal example which on your system generated the image you provided.

Comment: That will be your font's notdef character which it shows if you request a character not in the font. No font has every unicode character.

Comment: There are several \triangleright symbols defined by various packages.   See https://ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive?lang=en

Comment: I knew no font has all characters, but I thought `\triangleright` was one of the basic characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could design your own symbol with TikZ:

[image]

This is a comparison between `\triangleright` and the new symbol `\newtr` in the standard font. Of course, you can adjust the tikz picture any way you want. Since your font doesn't have the `\triangleright` glyph, adjust however looks good to you.

More information on designing your own symbol can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/480768/125871).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\newtr}{\mathrel{\tikz{\draw[line join=round] (0:.6ex)--(120:.6ex)--(240:.6ex)--cycle;}}}

\begin{document}

$a\triangleright b\newtr c$

$a\newtr b\triangleright c$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, it's a simple enough solution and it allowed me to customize it such that it fits better with the font.